# I Want A Countdown That Accepts A Custom Input

Tags: python, time

So i have tried my absolute hardest to try and get my code to work what i want is a input responsive countdown can anyone help?

```
    print ("Would You like To Start A Countdown? Y/N (CASE SENSITIVE)")
countdownyn = input (':')
if countdownyn == ('Y'):
    print ("Please Enter Your Designated Time To Countdown From")
x = input (':')
def countdown(x) :
    while x> 0:
        print (x)
        print ("")
        time.sleep(1)
        x = x1
    if x ==0:
        print("BLAST OFF!")
countdown(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: `x = int(input(':'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues that I won't list, but here are the fixes to help. Maybe.  If you're using Python 3, change the raw_input to input.

```
import time

def countdown(x) :
    while x > 0:
        print (x)
        print ("")
        time.sleep(1)
        x = x - 1
    print("BLAST OFF!")

countdownyn = raw_input ('Would You like To Start A Countdown? Y/N (CASE SENSITIVE): ')
if countdownyn == ('Y'):
    x = raw_input ('Please Enter Your Designated Time To Countdown From: ')
    countdown(int(x))
```

Output with the required pauses:

```
Would You like To Start A Countdown? Y/N (CASE SENSITIVE): Y
Please Enter Your Designated Time To Countdown From: 10
10

9

8

7

6

5

4

3

2

1

BLAST OFF!
```

****EDIT****

To get you going further...:

```
import time

def countdown(ticks) :
    for tick in range(ticks, 0, -1):
        print (tick)
        print ("")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("BLAST OFF!")



while True:
    countdownyn = raw_input('Would You like To Start A Countdown? Y/N (CASE SENSITIVE): ')
    if countdownyn == 'Y':
        x = raw_input('Please Enter Your Designated Time To Countdown From: ')
        try:
            countdown(int(x))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid integer")
            continue
    elif countdownyn == 'N':
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter only Y or N")
```

Comment: thanks for this but now ive got an error that says 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: @J.D - continue using `input` instead of `raw_input` - `raw_input` is only for Python 2.x.

Comment: You're right. And I'm using Python 2.7. If you're using Python 3, change raw_input to input.

Comment: thank you so much your a life saver

Answer (score 0):

You never do anything to `x1`. Perhaps you meant `x-1`:

```
while x> 0:
    print (x)
    print ("")
    time.sleep(1)
    x = x-1 #here
```

Comment: im still getting an error called 'TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int''

Comment: @J.D See Willem's comment on your question.